EntityFramework Include method is not working
Spent huge of time but do not understand why .Include(t => t.Nodes) does not return any Node entities:
public class TreeRepository : ITreeRepository
{
    private DataBaseContext dataBaseContext;

    public TreeRepository(DataBaseContext dataBaseContext)
    {
        this.dataBaseContext = dataBaseContext;
    }

    public async Task<ITree> GetTreeAsync(string name)
    {
        var tree = dataBaseContext.Tree.Include(t => t.Nodes).SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == name);

        if (tree == null)
        {
            var t = await dataBaseContext.Tree.AddAsync(new TreeTable { Name = name });
            await dataBaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            tree = t.Entity;
        }

        return tree;
    }
}

The row below
var tree = dataBaseContext.Tree.Include(t => t.Nodes).SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == name)

initialize .Include(t => t.Nodes)
Nodes are empty
Nodes filled
.Include(t => t.Nodes) should return nodes entities if they exist
Attach addititonal code
DataBaseContext.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Db.Tables;

namespace FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Db
{
    public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) : base(options) {}

        public DbSet<JournalTable> Journal { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NodeTable> Node { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TreeTable> Tree { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TreeTable>().ToTable("Tree"); //.Navigation(e => e.Nodes).AutoInclude();
            modelBuilder.Entity<NodeTable>().ToTable("Node");
            modelBuilder.Entity<JournalTable>().ToTable("Journal");
        }
    }
}

NodeTable.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Infrastructure.Entity;

namespace FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Db.Tables
{
    [Table("Node")]
    public class NodeTable : INode
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public long TreeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TreeId")]
        public virtual TreeTable Tree { get; set; }

        public long ParentNodeId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

TreeTable.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Infrastructure.Entity;

namespace FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Db.Tables
{
    [Table("Tree")]
    public class TreeTable : ITree
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        IEnumerable<INode> ITree.Nodes => Nodes;

        public virtual List<NodeTable> Nodes { get; set; }
    }
}

INode.cs
namespace FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Infrastructure.Entity
{
    public interface INode
    {
        long Id { get; set; }

        long TreeId { get; set; }

        long ParentNodeId { get; set; }

        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

ITree.cs
namespace FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Infrastructure.Entity
{
    public interface ITree
    {
        long Id { get; set; }

        string Name { get; set; }

        IEnumerable<INode> Nodes { get; }
    }
}

Startup.cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Db;
using FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.Middleware;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Repository;
using FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic.DAL.Infrastructure.Repository;

namespace FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddTransient<GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()?.DisplayName ?? x.FullName);
            });

            services.AddTransient<IJournalRepository, JournalRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<INodeRepository, NodeRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<ITreeRepository, TreeRepository>();

            services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataBaseConnectionString")));

            //services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLConnectionString")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "FxNet.Web.Def.Api.Diagnostic v1"));
            }

            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataBaseContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}


I'm not sure if I understand your question right. .Include() doesn't change the value that's returned from the query. What it does is automatically loads the referenced navigation properties using the same query, potentially saving database round trips.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

As I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/ we can siplify the using construction of initialization dbContext in each fuction (like using (var context = new BloggingContext())). And it works fine except .Include()

Added key classes and interfaces, SQL will check. Thank you

SQL query looks like:  exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(2) [t].[Id], [t].[Name]
FROM [Tree] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Name] = @__name_0',N'@__name_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__name_0=N'Root1'. No any additional subrequests when we call first row

The same, Nodes are empty. I also tried to rename the interface Nodes property

Solved, I used System.Data.Entity in TreeRepository, changed into Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and it stars working. Magic

Resolved! I used the old library System.Data.Entity. Replaced it with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Include method started working correctly.
